# android: calling Button.setText() causes undesired relocation of Button

Tags: java, android, button, view, tablelayout

I'm having this problem where a `TableLayout` of `Button`s is relocating all `Button` objects whenever i call `Button.setText(String)`.  i've given no indication that the `View` should be moved...  and i really don't want it to.  if anyone knows how to keep these `Views` from moving (without a whole lot of hassle if possible), please let me know.

i'm using some unorthodox methods for getting the screen setup.  here's the code:

static_grid_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:gravity="center">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn17"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn18"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn19"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn20"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

MainActivity.java: the part of particular interest will be here:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM "+DbSchema.ProductSchema.TABLE_NAME+
        " ORDER BY "+DbSchema.ProductSchema.COLUMN_PRIORITY+" ASC";
updateList(listQuery(query));
fillPage(mPage);
setContentView(mPage);
```

toward the bottom of the code in the `onResume()` override.  here is the undesired behavior in an image.  the `Button`s ONLY get that retarded y offset when i call setText().  if i call setText("") [empty String] the location of the button does not change.  what gives?

[image]

Comment: update: the y offset seems to be directly proportional to the number of text lines on the button.  the more lines of text, the further south it moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this is a known issue with TableLayouts.  this was reported several times, looking back as far as early 2010.  you can find the bug report here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6428

if you have anything to add, or you have a related issue, please post a bug report.

**FIX**: to fix the issue, i ended up filling the blank buttons with newlines as i filled the grid out.  that way everything was offset together.  nice, neat, even.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the text you are writing into the button, I suspect the buttons are too small for the amount of text you are inserting if setText("") doesn't change the layout.

Also, in your first tablerow, remove android:layout_height="fill_parent".

That line will try to make that row fill the entire table, change it to wrap_content and if the text isn't too much to fit in the button, the layout should not shift.